# Is scaling mapping uniformly continuous for any metric in $R$?

Tags: real-analysis

For example, is $f(x)=2x$ as a function of $R\rightarrow R$ uniformly continuous for a general metric $d(x,y)$?

Or is the following true?

$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta $, such that whenever $d(x,y)<\delta$, then $d(2x,2y)<\epsilon $.

Comment: Could you say something more about what led you to this question? It looks like the kind of thing I would see (or would set) as an exercise in a course on real analysis

Comment: The answer, by the way, is "no"

Comment: Yes, I am learning real analysis on myself. It seems I should ask this types of question at math.exchange?

Comment: Do you have a counterexamples? Thanks.

Comment: user758236. Are you looking for a metric that induces the euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Hint: you want a metric which somehow makes "distances larger" near points which are far from the origin

Answer (score 1):

Nope, you can monkey around with the metric more and more as you go further out.  For example, define the metric

$$d(x,y) = |e^x - e^y|.$$

Can you show that this metric is equivalent to the Euclidean metric?  Can you show that $f(x) = 2x$ is not uniformly continuous with respect to this metric?

Comment: I see, since $d(2x,2y) = d(x,y) |e^x+e^y|$, it's not uniformly continuous.  This is a good counterexample. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\phi$ switch 0 and 2, and be identity elsewhere. Let $d(x,y)=|\phi(x)-\phi(y)|$. Then the continuity of $f$ in the metric $d$ is equivalent to the continuity of $\phi \circ f \circ \phi^{-1}$ in the usual metric, which is not continuous near 1.

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions